# NSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex: withObject: Not Working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have a mutable array that, originally, I was having trouble with the scope.  I got some advice on how to fix that (which worked), but now the array will not replace the objects at a given index.

Here is the code:

.h file:

```
@interface myViewController: UIViewController {
  NSMutableArray *myArray;
}
```

.m file:

```
-(id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self){
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
  for (int x=0; x<6; x++) {
    [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]; //This adds the numbers just fine
  }
  [myArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] atIndex:0]; //This does not insert the number 1 into index 0
}
```

I've tried other ways to insert, such as:

```
replaceObjectAtIndex: withObject
```

And some others, but none of them worked....

I would greatly appreciate any help as this is the only thing standing between me and finishing my first app.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems correct to me and actually works

Comment: My first thought would be to use self.myArray instead of myArray (everywhere, but especially where you allocate it).  Are you using ARC?

Comment: how to initialize the class? is not that they use - init? trying to debug

Comment: @Inafziger I don't know what ARC is.... Someone mentioned that in my previous question about the scope of myArray.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110613/universal-array-in-objective-c

Comment: BTW, this is not my whole code, just a snippet relating to the NSMutableArray.  I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: ARC is a very important concept to at least know enough about to know whether or not you are using it.  The short version (to answer the question) though is:  When you created the new project, did you click the box that said "Use Automatic Reference Counting?"

Comment: @Inafziger I do not recall if I pressed a box saying that.

Comment: Do you get a compiler warning or build error if you try to call `release` on an object?

Comment: Okay, do this:  Select `Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC...`.  A window will open which shows your source files.  If you are already using ARC, there will be a yellow triangle to the right of the file names and when you click on it, at the bottom it will say "`Target currently uses ARC`".

Comment: How are you determining what works and what doesn't?

Comment: @Ken Thomases I have an if statement that if the value at index: 0 is 0, then it shows a message saying "zero", and another if statement that if the value at index 0 is 1, then it shows a message saying "one"

Comment: Well, if the value is nil then comparing it to 0 will still show as true....

Comment: @user1165664, much easier to do `NSLog(@"%@", myArray);`. I suspect you'll see that Inafziger is correct and the array is `nil`.

Comment: it does appear that nothing is getting entered into the array.... So what is going on then????

Answer (score 3):

First, class names should be capitalized.   I say "first" because this indicates that you aren't following convention and that can lead to problems in comprehension, if not flat out bugs.

Secondly, are you sure the `init` method is being invoked at all?  If your object is instantiated by the interface file load, then it likely isn't and the array is likely nil.

Comment: Your `init` method is likely not being called (try putting an `NSLog(@"Hello");` in it) and, thus, the instance variable `myArray` is `nil`.   Or put `NSLog(@"%@", myArray);` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: @user1165664 what bbum is trying to say is, don't put `myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in the `init` method. Instead, put it in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yeah... that.  That'll work *only* if `myArray` is never used before `viewDidLoad` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call the addSubview of your current view methode before.

```
YouViewNewController *youViewNewController=[[YouViewNewController alloc]init];

[self.view addSubview:youViewNewController.view]; // Calls viewDidLoad.
```

this work for me,

```
-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self){
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Lancement...");
}
return self;
```

}

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
   NSLog(@"Calcul...");

   for (int x=0; x<6; x++) 
    {
          [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]; //This adds the numbers just fine
    }
    [myArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] atIndex:0]; //This does not insert the number 1 into index 0

    NSLog(@"%i", [[myArray objectAtIndex:0]intValue]);
}
```

it works !

Answer (score 0):

The designated initializer for `UIViewController` is `-initWithNibName:bundle:`. You should override that rather than `-init`. Your `-init` is not getting called, so you are never assigning anything to `myArray`; it just remains `nil`.